Davenport Constant of Symmetric Group S5
I am working on computing the Davenport constant $D(G)$ of symmetric groups, which is the minimal number d such that every sequence of d elements, possibly with repetitions, of a fixed group is one-product. In other words, there is always some subsequence where the product of the elements in some order is the identity element. For example for $S_3$, the Davenport constant is 4 since every sequence of four elements we can always get identity element, however there are some maximal one product-free sequences of length 3, e.g. {(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)} or {(1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,2)}.
There is nothing done for symmetric groups and I am using combinatorial proofs, since computations (even with computer) are extremely huge. We know the constant for all non-abelian groups of order at most 42 and $A_5$, which appears in some paper, hence we know values for $S_3$, $S_4$, $A_5$, $S_3^2$...
In particular, now I am focusing on $S_5$ and $S_3^n$. Could someone give me a hint about which strategy to follow, in case you come up with a nice strategy? For $S_5$ I am almost done, since I know that $D(A_5)=9$, i.e., every 9 elements in $A_5$ we get identity and also (almost proved) 8 odd elements in $S_5$. Moreover, maximal one-product free sequences of lemgth 8 in $A_5$ consist of eight 5-cycles, hence using this information I know that $D(S_5)\le 12$, and also $D(S_5)\ge 10$. I am stuck here, any ideas?? Thanks a lot in advance!

Also posted to Overflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/474181/davenport-constant-ds-5-10-or-11 without notification to either site, a violation.
